# How to add new lines to stdout in perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have this piece of code at the end of a .cgi-file:

```
if ($cmd eq 'set'){
         my @args = ('ranking', 'set', $bug_id, $rank);
         system(@args) == 0
           or die "system @args failed: $?";
 }
```

You can input the data and it's interpreted as a system command. An example output on the HTML-page is the following:

```
Current ranking is 1, I will decrement all bugs with higher ranking by one Not shifting any bug, since there is another one with ranking Bug 111 removed from ranking Bug 111 inserted into ranking at position 1
```

(all in one line)

But I need to format the output like this:

```
Current ranking is 1,
I will decrement all bugs with higher ranking by one
Not shifting any bug, since there is another one with ranking
Bug 111 removed from ranking
Bug 111 inserted into ranking at position 1
```

How can I add those new lines to the HTML-page?

Comment: What prints HTML output? System?

Comment: The piece of code above prints the output.

Comment: You seem to be confused between standard text output and HTML. Try piping the output of your code above through a second perl one-liner: `| perl  -pe 's/$/<br>/'` before sending your output into an HTML document.

Comment: The HTML is embedded in the .cgi file. After the above codesnippet there's just a `print "</body>";`, so where should `| perl -pe 's/$/<br>/'` be placed?

Comment: The way your code is currently written I assume that system is producing output. If you wish to alter the output that system is producing you need to capture it into your program, and then alter it, and then print it.  Capturing can be done pretty easily with Capture::Tiny, or with backticks, or less simply with one of the IPC::Open* modules.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand; this is all automated and direct. Maybe try adding this line before the `system` call (or the `if`) above then?: `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";` (Like in this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Example .)

Comment: Pretty at the beginning of the script there's already this: `print $cgi->header('text/html');` and if I try your suggestion then it simply prints: Content-type: text/plain

Comment: @DavidO how would you implement that in this case?

Comment: Then change that to be `'text/plain'`, or else you will have to modify your `ranking` command to output **HTML** rather than plain text. You seem to have a conflict between what your page is declaring vs. what your program is outputting (html vs. plain text; they are **different**).

Comment: I see, but if I change it to text/plain then the entire HTML page isn't 'rendered'. Just the code appears. Maybe you  are right I need to modify the `ranking` command, but is there a solution for this problem? Would be interesting

Comment: Well, the other solution is to "capture" and massage the output of the `ranking` command as @DavidO is suggesting. I will put proposed code into an answer below in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `system` call with the backtick operator in Perl to capture your output into a variable, then massage the output before printing:

```
if ($cmd eq 'set'){
         $_ = `ranking set $bug_id $rank`;
         $? == 0
           or die "command 'ranking set $bug_id $rank' failed: $?";
         s/$/<br>/mg;
         print;
 }
```

The `/m` on the `s/` is needed so that the text is treated as `m`ultiple lines (`$` matches at `\n`). The `/g` says "do all occurrences" (all lines).

Maybe this will work for you. (Caveat: untested.)

Comment: You can just `s/\n/<br>/g` without `/m`.

Comment: True. I wanted to leave the `\n`s in for readability though, so would suggest `s/\n/<br>\n/g`. (`$` doesn't **match** `\n`, it zero-matches just before the `\n`.)

Comment: Injection bug!! `&` and `<` should also be escaped